# DSolve does not work

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic, differential-geometry

I am trying to solve this coupled nonlinear pdes for $\kappa(x,t)$ and $\tau(x,t)$:

[image]

where $\zeta_1 = \kappa(x,t)$, $\zeta_2 = 0$. I used this code
[image]

```
ζ1[t, s] := k[t, s];
ζ2[t, s] := 0;
DSolve[{D[τ[t, s], t] == -ζ2[t, s] k[t, s] - D[ζ1[t, s], s], 
  D[k[t, s], t] == -τ[t, s] ζ2[t, s] - 
    D[(ζ1[t, s] k[t, s] + D[ζ2[t, s], s] )/τ[t, s], s]}, {k, τ}, t, s]
```

but the Mathematica repeats the code like that:

[image]

and sometimes with different values for $\zeta_1\,\,and\,\, \zeta_2$, it repeats the same equation again.
Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: `DSolve` returns unevaluated when it cannot obtain a solution.  Perhaps, there is no analytical solution.  Do you have reason to believe otherwise?

Comment: @bbgodfrey,It has a solution because some colleagues use Mathematica 7 and it gives a solution with them but with Mathematica 12 or other versions doesn't work. I wonder why it does not work with me?!. At the beginning I thought the problem from my laptop but after trying another laptops still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by the OP in a comment above, the system of PDEs in the question has a solution.  It can be obtained by assuming that `D[ζ1[t, s], s] == 0`, in which case the first equation requires that `k` must be a function of `t` only, and `τ` a function of `s` only.  Inserting this result into the second equation causes it to simplify into two terms one a function of `s` only and the other a function of `t` only.  So, each of those terms must be constant, which allows `k` and `τ` to be determined by

```
solk = Flatten@DSolve[k'[t] == c k[t]^2, k, t] /. C[1] -> ck /. {t} -> {t, s}
(* {k -> Function[{t, s}, 1/(-c t - ck)]} *)
solτ = Flatten@DSolve[τ'[s] == c τ[s]^2, τ, s] /. C[1] -> cτ /. {s} -> {t, s}
(* {τ -> Function[{t, s}, 1/(-c s - cτ)]} *)
```

Inserting these into the original equations then yields

```
{D[τ[t, s], t] == -ζ2[t, s] k[t, s] - D[ζ1[t, s], s],
 D[k[t, s], t] == -τ[t, s] ζ2[t, s] - D[(ζ1[t, s] k[t, s] + D[ζ2[t, s], s])/τ[t, s], s]}
    /. Flatten[{solk, solτ}]
(* {True, True} *)
```

It is possible, of course, that there are other solution.  This question illustrates the need for `DSolve` to be improved, especially with respect to systems of first order PDEs.